# How to override the default focus css style of react-tab?

Tags: css, less, react-tabs

I am using react-tab to create an interface  like this

[image]

However if i click on the tab, it will turn into this:

[image]

It is the default css style when the tab gets focus.

I have tried this css (in less) but it is unable to override the default style:

```
.react-tabs [role=tab],
.react-tabs [role=tablist],
.react-tabs [role=tab]:focus,
.react-tabs [role=tablist]:focus, {
  border-top: none ;
  border-left: none ;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
}
```

How can I override the css styles?

In addition, is there anywhere to make the above css more concise? For one I would like to be able to combine `[role=tab]` and `[role=tablist]` into a single selector.

*EDIT*

The html markup of the tab

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your CSS: the last comma in `.react-tabs [role=tablist]:focus, /* <-- */` must be removed.

#### Demo

```css
.react-tabs {
  height: 20px;
}

.react-tabs [role=tab]  { background: orange; } /* correct version */
.react-tabs [role=tab], { background: blue; } /* won't work */
```

```html
<div class="react-tabs">
  <div class="something" role="tab">Want to change this guy</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The structure is actually more like `<div class="example"><div class="something" role="tab"> Want to change this guy</div></div>`. I tried your solution but it does not work.

Comment: Ok this changes everything. Then just remove the last comma and see if the styles get applied (inspect element).

Answer (score 1):

You must override all default properties of `:focus` and `:focus:after`.

This code below works for me:

```
  .react-tabs [role=tab]:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
    border-color: none;
    border-bottom-color: $yourColor;
    outline: none;
  }

  .react-tabs [role=tab]:focus:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 5px;
    left: -4px;
    right: -4px;
    bottom: -5px;
    background: transparent; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide `outline: 0` to your code.

`outline` by default appears over many form elements like `input` & `button`, when they are active or focussed. So you have to manually make it disappear.

> Outlines differ from borders in the following ways:
>
> - Outlines do not take up space, they are drawn above the content.
> - Outlines may be non-rectangular. They are rectangular in    Gecko/Firefox. But e.g. Opera draws a non-rectangular shape around
>     the construct.

Refer code:

```
.react-tabs [role=tab],
.react-tabs [role=tablist],
.react-tabs [role=tab]:focus,
.react-tabs [role=tablist]:focus, {
  border-top: none ;
  border-left: none ;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
  outline: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? Can you provide your code or make a fiddle then maybe?

Comment: Maybe try `outline: 0 !important;`

Comment: nay, it does not work. It is rather difficult to construct a standalone example (e.g. codepen does not support `import ... from ...` es6 syntax). I will give it a go.